# Pass other field input value as parameter in jqueryFormvalidator

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-form-validator

I have to check whether the username and password is correct or not.
So i want to pass both username and password as parameter to the function in controller.
I am able to send password but not able to send both.

```
<div class="control-field">
    <input type="text" id="ad-username" data-validation="required" data-validation-if-checked="isSecured" name="adusername" placeholder="AD Username"/>
</div>

<div class="control-field">
    <input type="text" id="ad-password" data-validation="required server"  name="adpassword"  placeholder ="AD Password" data-validation-url="/FormValidation/CheckPassword" />
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public JsonResult CheckPassword(string adusername, string adpassword) {

  FormValidator validator = new FormValidator();

  if (true) {
    validator.valid = false;
    validator.message = "User name and password did not match";
  }

  return Json(validator);

}
```

jQuery Validation :

```
    $.validate(
  {
      modules: 'security',
      form: '#existing-form',
      validateOnBlur: false, // disable validation when input looses focus
      errorMessagePosition: 'element', // Instead of 'element' which is default
      scrollToTopOnError: false,// Set this property to true if you have a long form
      language: {
          requiredFields: "This field is required"
      }
  });
```

Comment: show your controller.

Comment: ok, and now your jquery post function?

Comment: Don't have any special post function. I am expecting the field name="adpassword" should carry both the name and password to server .